# How do I copy the depth buffer to CPU memory in Direct3D 9?

Tags: directx, depth-buffer

I have code in **OpenGL** that uses `glReadPixels` to copy the depth buffer to a CPU memory buffer:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, dbuf);
```

How do I achieve the same in Direct3D?

I have looked at a similar [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41958/how-to-capture-the-screen-in-directx-9-to-a-raw-bitmap-in-memory-without-using-d) which gives a solution for copying the *color* buffer. I've tried to write similar code to copy the depth buffer:

```
IDirect3DSurface9* d3dSurface;
d3dDevice->GetDepthStencilSurface(&d3dSurface);

D3DSURFACE_DESC d3dSurfaceDesc;
d3dSurface->GetDesc(&d3dSurfaceDesc);

IDirect3DSurface9* d3dOffSurface;
  d3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
  d3dSurfaceDesc.Width,
  d3dSurfaceDesc.Height,
  D3DFMT_D32F_LOCKABLE,
  D3DPOOL_SCRATCH,
  &d3dOffSurface,
  NULL
);

// FAILS: D3DERR_INVALIDCALL
D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface(
  d3dOffSurface,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  d3dSurface,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  D3DX_FILTER_NONE,
  0
);

// Copy from offscreen surface to CPU memory ...
```

The code fails on the call to `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface`. It returns the error value `D3DERR_INVALIDCALL`.

So, is something wrong with my code? How can I copy the depth buffer contents?

Comment: as i remember it ( dx9 is not my expertise ) you have to write it manualy, since it was protected by the drivers...

Comment: @Tordin: I'm a DirectX newbie. Any pointers on how I can copy it manually? :)

Comment: I think you had to write it yourself, so when you are writing models you had to write to a specific buffer to store depth in.

Comment: @Tordin: A MSDN page on Vista display drivers seems to imply that drivers have to support copying depth buffer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540530.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean GPU instead of CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can acquire a reference to the depth-stencil surface for the device (if one exists for that device) by calling `GetDepthStencilSurface`. If the method returns successfully, you can lock the bits of the resulting surface using the [`LockRect` method of the surface interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This gives you a [locked rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the bits of the surface accessible via the `pBits` member. You will need to use the `Pitch` as well as surface format information obtained from `GetDesc` to interpret the bits correctly.

I don't know why you are trying to use the surface-copying routines as you are, but I don't believe they are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the copy is necessary because in general you cannot lock the depth buffer. As far as I know you need your depth buffer to use a lockable format to be able to copy the contained data directly into your own containers. 
D24S8 for example is a format which prevents locking the depth buffer.
(I am not allowed to add comments, so as an answer ...)